# Regex to check character and integer inside a string

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame and I want to flag all the elements inside this which contains character or character plus integer value.

After a little bit of search, I could make this regex but its not giving the expected output:

```
([A-Za-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

**Expected output**

```
alpha -  True
Alpha1 - True
A35. 1ha-True
Alp1Ha - True
A pha6-  True
12345 -  False
0 -      False
-23442 - False
```

Comment: Try `"\\b[A-Za-z]+(?:[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*)?\\b"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked perfectly with the sample i have mentioned above but its giving wrong output when i ran it against my dataframe. for example, i am testing with a single vector of 420 entities and its giving me an output of 2200 entries.

Comment: So, what are the actual *requirements*?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that the regex should work with any type of string which follow the structure as mentioned above.

Comment: Try `^[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z].*$`, does it [work](https://regex101.com/r/FrBubN/1)?

Comment: Great, then please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56965979/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sco8CJ/1)

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+$
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z].*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FrBubN/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `[^A-Za-z]*` - 0 or more chars other than ASCII letters
- `[A-Za-z]` - an ASCII letter
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.